# Event only firing as inline JS statement

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have the following code in a Nuxtjs app in SSR mode.

```html
<Component
      :is="author.linkUrl ? 'a' : 'div'"
      v-bind="!author.linkUrl && { href: author.linkUrl, target: '_blank' }"
      @click="author.linkUrl ? handleAnalytics() : null"
    >
```

The click event in case it's an `a` tag, will only fire if it's written as `handleAnalytics()`, but `handleAnalytics` will not work.

Don't get me wrong the code is working, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Without the parenthesis, the function won't be called, just assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With classical event binding (`@click="handleAnalytics`), Vue will auto bind it for you because it sees it's a function.

But when provided a ternary condition, it's not auto binded but wrapped into a anonymous function instead. So you have to call it with parenthesis otherwise you're just returning the function without executing it.

To be clearer, you can write it this way: `@click="() => author.linkUrl ? handleAnalytics() : null"`

---

*Note*: when having a dynamic tag component, I'd suggest to use the `render` function instead.

This is **an advanced technique**, but this way you won't bind things to an element that doesn't need it (without having the kind of hack to return `null`).

Example:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    author: { type: Object, required: true },
  },
  render (h: CreateElement) {
    const renderLink = () => {
      return h('a', {
        attrs: {
          href: author.linkUrl,
          target: '_blank',
        },
        on: {
          click: this.handleAnalytics 
        },
      )
    }

    const renderDiv = () => {
      return h('div')
    }
    
    return this.author.linkUrl ? renderLink() : renderDiv()
  }
}
```

Documention: [Vue2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth), [Vue3](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! In fact I was wondering about using JSX only for this case :). I had some doubts about this being handled by Vuejs internal logic and you explained it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript functions are a reference to an object. Just like in any other language you need to store this reference in memory.

Here are a few examples that might help you understand on why its not working:

```js
function handleAnalytics() { return 'bar' };

const resultFromFunction = handleAnalytics();
const referenceFn = handleAnalytics;
```

`resultFromFunction` will have `bar` as it's value, while `referenceFn` will have the reference to the function `handleAnalytics` allowing you to do things like:

```js
if (someCondition) {
  referenceFn();
}
```

A more practical example:

```js
function callEuropeanUnionServers() { ... }
function callAmericanServers() { ... }

// Where would the user like for his data to be stored
const callAPI = user.preferesDataIn === 'europe' 
  ? callEuropeanUnionServers
  : callEuropeanUnionServers;

// do some logic
// ...

// In this state you won't care which servers the data is stored.
// You will only care that you need to make a request to store the user data.
callAPI();
```

In your example what happens is that you are doing:

```js
@click="author.linkUrl ? handleAnalytics() : null"
```

What happens in pseudo code is:

1. Check the author has a `linkUrl`
2. If yes, then **EXECUTE** `handleAnalytics` first and then the result of it pass to handler `@click`
3. If not, simply pass `null`

Why it works when you use `handleAnalytics` and not `handleAnalytics()`?

1. Check the author has a `linkUrl`
2. If yes, then pass the **REFERENCE** `handleAnalytics` to handler `@click`
3. If not, simply pass `null`

### Summary

When using `handleAnalytics` you are passing a reference to `@click`. When using `handleAnalytics()` you are passing the result returned from `handleAnalytics` to `@click` handler.